# Extract numbers from excel cell ERROR

Tags: excel, numbers, extract

From this community I found a useful formula to extract numbers from excel cells.

An example of cell is:

> Theoretical pI: 9.53

And the formula is:

```
=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A4;LEN(A4)-FIND(":";A4));".";REPT(" ";LEN(A4));2);LEN(A4))))
```

However what the formula returned is not 9,53 but 196030!

Can anybody point out why that happens?

Comment: Just tested this... and i get 9.53. Check your formula again, and make sure the cell format is set to general

Comment: try: `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A4;LEN(A4)-FIND(":";A4));".";REPT(" ";LEN(A4));2);LEN(A4)));".";","))`

Comment: If the numbers in your data are *always* the last part the entry and *always* come after a colon `:` then you should be able to use this formula: `=--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;":";REPT(" ";LEN(A1)));LEN(A1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested to use VBA, you can use this function or ignore it.

```
    Public Function getNumber(fromThis As Range) As Double
        Dim retVal As String
        Dim ltr As String, i As Integer, european As Boolean

        retVal = ""
        getNumber = 0
        european = False

        On Error GoTo last
        If fromThis.Value Like "*.*,*" Then
            european = True
        End If

        For i = 1 To Len(fromThis)
            ltr = Mid(fromThis, i, 1)
            If IsNumeric(ltr) Then
                retVal = retVal & ltr
            ElseIf ltr = "." And (Not european) And Len(retVal) > 0 Then
                retVal = retVal & ltr
            ElseIf ltr = "," And european And Len(retVal) > 0 Then
                retVal = retVal & "."
            End If
        Next i
        getNumber = CDbl(retVal)
last:
    End Function
```